# http.GetAsync(uri); Message "The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

In following his video example on Channel 9 "[Developing Universal Windows Apps with C# and XAML: (05) Building a service](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Developing-Universal-Windows-Apps-with-C-and-XAML/05)" for "Building a service" I was able to get this to work back in March of 2015, since then made lots of additions to my project and system and now back to continuing this part of my project.

Running in debug it doesn't give me a specific reason why its failing other than:

```
-       e   {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}   Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
-       Exception   {"The parameter is incorrect.\r\n\r\nThe parameter is incorrect.\r\n"}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
+       [System.ArgumentException]  {"The parameter is incorrect.\r\n\r\nThe parameter is incorrect.\r\n"}  System.ArgumentException
-       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
+       [System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal] {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    IsFixedSize false   bool
    IsReadOnly  false   bool
+       Keys    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
+       Values  {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
-       Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
-       [0] {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}    object {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
    Key "RestrictedDescription" object {string}
    Value   "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"   object {string}
+       Non-Public members      
-       [1] {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}    object {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
    Key "RestrictedErrorReference"  object {string}
    Value   null    object
+       Non-Public members      
-       [2] {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}    object {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
    Key "RestrictedCapabilitySid"   object {string}
    Value   null    object
+       Non-Public members      
-       [3] {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}    object {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
    Key "__RestrictedErrorObject"   object {string}
-       Value   {System.Exception.__RestrictedErrorObject}  object {System.Exception.__RestrictedErrorObject}
-       RealErrorObject COM Object  object {System.__ComObject}
+       base    COM Object  System.MarshalByRefObject {System.__ComObject}
+       Non-Public members      
+       Interface View      
-       Dynamic View    Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object  
    Empty   "No further information on this object could be discovered" string
+       Non-Public members      
+       Non-Public members      
-       [4] {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}    object {System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}
    Key "__HasRestrictedLanguageErrorObject"    object {string}
    Value   false   object {bool}
+       Non-Public members      
    HelpLink    null    string
    HResult -2147024809 int
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
    Message "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n\r\nThe parameter is incorrect.\r\n"    string
    Source  ""  string
    StackTrace  null    string
    TargetSite  null    System.Reflection.MethodBase
+       Static members      
+       Non-Public members      
    Handled false   bool
    Message "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"   string
```

I read and applied this resolution "[Error Message: The Parameter Is Incorrect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/199025)" at the Microsoft Support site with no success.  Because I do have several language packs installed, but the default is set to English, so I don't see how this is causing the failure.

My MainPageViewModel that handles the OnNavigatedTo and http.GetAsync(uri):

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
{
    using (var http = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.StatusCode != Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}

public async override void OnNavigatedTo(object navigationParameter, NavigationMode navigationMode, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
{
    try
    {
        var service = System.IO.Path.Combine(this._settings.WebApiBase, Parameters.TSUser);
        var tsuser = await GetAsync<IEnumerable<NathsarTS.DataModels.Models.TSUser>>(new Uri(service));
```

other parts of the project that make up the fields above:

```
    public class Settings : ISettings
    {
        public Settings()
        {
            WebApiBase = "http://localhost:58317/api/";
     ...
    }

    public static class Parameters
    {
        public const string TSUser = "TSUsers";
     ...
    }

    public class TSUsersController : ApiController
    {
        private NathsarTSEntities db = new NathsarTSEntities();

        // GET: api/TSUsers
        public IQueryable<TSUser> GetTSUsers()
        {
            return db.TSUsers;
        }
     ...
    }
```

The message of the Exception Message after letting it run through is:

**Value does not fall within the expected range.**

What else do I need to check to get this work?

**Additional Research:**

After creating a basic App with a WebApi (2014 SQLExpress Edmx stuff) and a PCL (For my shared Table classes) I discover something rather bazaar when executing the http.GetAsync(uri) I get an Exception that is related to the ListBox I'm using:

1. ) I'm implementing a Window Phone Pivot I got from the Window Dev Center for My Windows App project of the Universal Solution. [XAML FlipView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-FlipView-control-0ae45312)
2. This project is uses the *SeletedItem* for its Binding to the FlipView and in this case it doesn't cause an Exception when I execute http.GetAsync(uri),
3. however when I use the *SelectedIndex* I get the Exception.
4. the reason for using http.GetAsync(uri) is to retrieve the items for the ListBox from a 2014 SQLExpress Database and for some reason it triggers this Exception.

**Current Solution:**

My acceptable work around was to remove the Binding from the XAML and create it in code:

```
var service = System.IO.Path.Combine("http://localhost:53397/api/", "TSPivotMenus");
var tspivotmenus = await GetAsync<IEnumerable<TSPivotMenu>>(new Uri(service));

this.TSMainMenu.ItemsSource = tspivotmenus;
Binding binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedIndex"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    ElementName = this.TSMainFlipView.Name
};
this.TSMainMenu.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedIndexProperty, binding);
```

But, it would be great to find out why this happens!

**My Conlusion:**

After further research and meditation the only thing I can see why this Exception is being raised is when the **ListBox** doesn't have any items to select or default to while its waiting for the *async* method to complete so I can fill it with items.

So the **http.GetAsync**(uri) is not actually causing the **Exception** *directly* but *in-directly* because I need the data from it for the **ListBox**.

If anyone has free time to test and confirm this I could mark this as **Answered**.